convergence of $|x_{n+1}-x_n|\longrightarrow 0$ when $x_n$ is a sequence of argmin
I would like to prove this fact.
Let the sequence $v_n\in C(\Omega)$ and suppose that for any $n$ there exists a unique minimum point $x_n \in \Omega$ for the function $v_n$, i.e  $v_n(x_n)<v_n(x) \forall x\neq x_n$. Let suppose that $|v_{n+1}-v_{n}|\longrightarrow 0$ uniformly for $n\longrightarrow \infty $. Then $|x_{n+1}-x_{n}|\longrightarrow 0$ for $n\longrightarrow \infty $.
I am trying to prove this fact. I have already try without success using this fact:
Let $v, v_n\in C(\Omega)$ and suppose that there exists a unique minimum point $x_0 \in \Omega$ for the function $v$. Let suppose that $v_{n+1}$ converges to $v$ uniformly for $n\longrightarrow \infty $. Then there exists a sequence  $x_n \in \Omega$ such that $x_{n}\longrightarrow x_0$ for $n\longrightarrow \infty $ and    $v_n(x_n)\leq v_n(x) \forall x\neq x_n$.
Thanks for all helps!

The statement is false.
Consider $\Omega = [-1,1]$ and $v_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}x$.
Then each $v_n$ has a unique minimum point $x_n = (-1)^{n+1}$
and $$||v_{n+1} - v_{n}||_\infty = \left|\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1}\right| \to 0$$ but $|x_{n+1} - x_n| \equiv 2 \not\to 0$
